# Getting the result of a domain entity in grails unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, grails, groovy

My service would throw an `InvalidOperationException` if the result of the query
`PaymentDetails.findByIdAndAmountDateCreatedGreaterThanEquals` is *NOT NULL*

The function aims to check if there are duplicate details from the last 5 minutes.
I'm trying to create a unit test for this but the function always returns `NULL` instead

```
        given:
        DateUtils.getCurrentDate() >> new Date()
        Date currentDate = new Date()
        Date twoMinutesBeforeCurrentDate = new Date()
        use (TimeCategory) {
            twoMinutesBeforeCurrentDate = currentDate - 2.minutes
        }

        long methodId = 3L
        BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal("5")

        PaymentDetails details = new PaymentDetails(amount: amount, id:methodId).save(flush: true)

        details.dateCreated = twoMinutesBeforeCurrentDate
        details.save(flush: true)

        when:
        service.validateTransactionDetails(methodId, amount)

        then:
        InvalidOperationException exception = thrown()
        ApiError.SAME_PAYMENT_DETAILS_WITH_PREVIOUS_TRANSACTION == exception.apiError
```

Here is my service method:

```
    Date currentDate = DateUtils.getCurrentDate()
    Date fiveMinutesBeforeCurrentDate = null

    use (TimeCategory) {
         fiveMinutesBeforeCurrentDate = currentDate-5.minutes
    }

    PaymentDetails details = PaymentDetails.findByIdAndAmountDateCreatedGreaterThanEquals(methodId, amount, fiveMinutesBeforeCurrentDate)

    if (details) {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(ApiError.SAME_PAYMENT_DETAILS_WITH_PREVIOUS_TRANSACTION)
    }
```

Thank you in advance! It's my first time debugging something from Grails and I'm having a hard time on this. Please be gentle. Lol.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `new PaymentDetails(amount: amount, id:methodId)` isn't really valid because `id`s are by default excluded from mass property binding so your `PaymentDetails` instance does not have the `id` you think it does (you can verify that by inspecting the object in the debugger if you like).  A better idea is to let the entity be assigned an `id` by the `save` method and then retrieve that value later to initiate the query.  This works:

```
import grails.testing.gorm.DataTest
import grails.testing.services.ServiceUnitTest
import groovy.time.TimeCategory
import spock.lang.Specification

class PaymentServiceSpec extends Specification implements ServiceUnitTest<PaymentService>, DataTest{

    @Override
    Class[] getDomainClassesToMock() {
        [PaymentDetails]
    }

    void "test payment details validation"() {
        given:
        Date currentDate = new Date()
        GroovySpy(DateUtils, global: true)
        1 * DateUtils.getCurrentDate() >> currentDate

        Date twoMinutesBeforeCurrentDate
        use (TimeCategory) {
            twoMinutesBeforeCurrentDate = currentDate - 2.minutes
        }

        BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal("5")

        PaymentDetails details = new PaymentDetails(amount: amount).save(flush: true)

        when:
        service.validateTransactionDetails(details.id, amount)

        then:
        InvalidOperationException exception = thrown()
        ApiError.SAME_PAYMENT_DETAILS_WITH_PREVIOUS_TRANSACTION == exception.apiError
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Hi sir! thank you so much for your help! I updated the query and still got a null value. After a few moments(Lol) I was able to notice that the cause is the `amount` which has a scale and precision setting on our database -_- Thank you once again!